# fetch запрос ITunes search API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

не могу понять в чем проблема, делаю get запрос через fetch, пытаюсь посмотреть что приходит, но ничего не работает

```
import React from 'react';

import './SearchLine.css';

export class SearchLine extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { data: []}
}


MakeARequest(request) {
    fetch("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson",
                {
                    mode:'no-cors'  
                }
            )
        .then(response => console.log(response));
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.MakeARequest('sia');
}

render() {
    return(
       <div>
        {this.state.data.length !==0?
            this.state.data.map(
                (data_iter, i) => {
                    return(
                        <div
                            DATA={data_iter}
                            key={i}
                        />
                    )
                }
            ): " "
        }
       </div>
    );
}}
```

в консоли браузера ничего не выводится статус запроса false, то есть все блокируется, не знаю почему, раньше ошибка вылетала на CORS, но в fetch запросе прописал "no-cors" но ничего не меняется[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так выглядит вывод

Answer (score 1):

Так нельзя. Вот тут доступно написано про кросдоменные запросы:
https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain

Насколько я знаю у itunes есть api. Посмотрите здесь.
https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

Можно на бэкенде организовать подгрузку данных и выдавать их во фронт

Comment: бэк часть не нужна, нужно все организовать через фронт. А почему так как у меня нельзя, я не понимаю в чем ошибка?

Comment: Раньше когда cors не было, было много взломов чужих страниц. Ты только представь себе сидишь ты вконтакте, а кто то всунул вредоносный код в онлайн кинотеатр и угнал твою учётку. Поэтому через браузеры это запретили. Почитай статью из первой ссылки